# How do I get the datetime object of today's 5pm in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to make a countdown app that will count down to today's 5pm. How would I do this with the datetime object? In short, I just want to retrieve the unix time of today's 5pm.

I looked at the doc, but I feel a little lost. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) with a [`datetime.time()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time):

```
fivepm = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.date.today(), 
    datetime.time(17, 0))
```

The [`datetime.datetime.combine()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) creates a new `datetime` instance from the date and time given.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(
...     datetime.date.today(), 
...     datetime.time(17, 0))
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 27, 17, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`datetime.datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(17))
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 27, 17, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replace()` if you have already `datetime.datetime` object:

Unfortunately, in order to have the exact time you need to clear also `second` and `microsecond`

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=17, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```